# Border disappears, when I use rotateX on element

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I am trying to create a **rotating ellipse** (*<div>* with *border-radius: 100%;*) and I would like to **border** has a **same width** always. However, border disappears when element rotating:

It could be border to have the same width regardless of the rotateX? Thank you for your answers.

**EDIT:**
[GCyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086875/border-disappears-when-i-use-rotatex-on-element/39086981#39086981), I thought something similar, but I cannot write values of border-width ​​manually. Ellipse rotates lineary using JavaScript:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var ellipse = document.getElementById('ellipse');
  var angle = 0;
  
  setInterval(function() {
    angle++;
    ellipse.style.transform = 'rotateX(' + angle + 'deg)';
  }, 20);
  
};
```

```css
section {
   perspective: 1000px;
}

#ellipse {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="ellipse"></div>
<section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of rotation, everything becomes thinner, so do the borders.

You can give a test increasing them. Example with a shadow:

```css
section {
   perspective: 1000px;
}

div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

#rotate45 {
  transform: rotateX(70deg);
  box-shadow:0  2px 1px , 0  -2px 1px;
}

#rotate90 {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  box-shadow:0  7px 2px , 0  -7px 2px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  Rotate 0°, it's OK:
  <div id="rotate0"></div>
  
  Rotate 45°, border is dashed:
  <div id="rotate45"></div>
  
  Rotate 90°, border is almost invisible:
  <div id="rotate90"></div>
<section>
```

---

**edit from your comment.**

If you include `border` thickness (or `shadow`) as well while rotation happens, it should help :

```css
section {
   perspective: 1000px;
}

div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  transition:1s;
}

#rotate45:hover {
  transform: rotateX(70deg);
  box-shadow:0  2px 1px , 0  -2px 1px;
}

#rotate90:hover {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  box-shadow:0  7px 2px , 0  -7px 2px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  Rotate 0°, it's OK:
  <div id="rotate0"></div>
  
  Rotate 45°: <i>hover it to see transition on transition and shadow</i>
  <div id="rotate45"></div>
  
  Rotate 90°: <i>hover it to see transition on transition and shadow</i>
  <div id="rotate90"></div>
<section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I cannot write values of border-width ​​manually. Ellipse rotates lineary using JavaScript.

Comment: @Mr.Human If you rotation goes through steps (via javascript or CSS transition/animation) you may include also thickness to your borders. I updated answer to show the idea via transition and shadow, just hover the box to rotate to see if this can be an hint :)